# Why does flush in asp.net appear not to be workig?

Tags: asp.net

I call flush but the page just hangs for 5second (purposely) then renders completely. Why isnt it showing me the first part then the last?

Firefox 7 and chrome both do this

code file

```
using System;

namespace ABC
{
    public class Test
    {
        static public void Apple()
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
hi
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
  starting
  <% ABC.Test.Apple(); %>
  <% WebApplication1._Default.RecurseMe(Response, @"/var/www/wordpress", 0); %>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you monitor the traffic with e.g. Ethereal or Microsoft Network Monitor or with the Google Chrome integrated tools? Maybe your server _is_ sending immediately but something on the browser-side hinders it to display?

Comment: @UweKeim: maybe, but what chrome tool does this? i just checked quickly and didnt see anything

Comment: I thought there is a network tool/tab showing what has been sent and received from the server?!?

Comment: @Uwe There is but it told me there was 5.5sec before receiving and ~1sec to receiving the data. So it looks like its one blast

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a web browser will show the page before it's done loading the HTML. Think about it this way.. there are tags that need to be closed before the page can be rendered correctly and  is a tag.

I'm not sure why you need to do this, but if you want to hide some data while it loads you should hide the area in a hidden div and then display it using javascript  after the time interval or some other method such as an AJAX callback.

Comment: Well if you think about it if i am stopping the thread for a second and flushing before i am doing some kind of test and i'd like to flush to see the pause happening ;)